# Data output as none using python

Tags: python-3.x

I made a simple code in python to output data in text format and the code is:

```
f = open("my.txt" , "w")
import string
for x in string.ascii_uppercase:
        for a in string.ascii_uppercase:
            b = print(x,a)
            f.write(str(b))

f.close()
```

the output should be like :

```
A A
A B
A C
```

In fact it is printed correctly in the screen but when i open the txt file it shows None None None....etc. What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print(something)` returns `None` in Python. So, when you write, `b = print(x,a)`, you are assigning b to the return value of print or None, which is why the file shows that.

If you want to write to the file and print, you can just say, `f.write(x + " " + a)`.

Comment: No problem. If this helped you out, please accept this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning print statement to variable which is wrong indeed, here is a quick fix:

```
f = open("my.txt" , "w")
import string
for x in string.ascii_uppercase:
    for a in string.ascii_uppercase:
        b = x + " " + a + "\n"
        f.write(str(b))

f.close()
```

Comment: Thx zatta for u help !

Answer (score 0):

Try this  :

```
f = open("my.txt" , "w")
import string
for x in string.ascii_uppercase:
   for a in string.ascii_uppercase: 
      b = print(x,a)
      f.write(str(x),str(b) )
f.close()
```

And i hope that i helped you

Comment: Thx Adelov for u help !